# How to set size and position of objects in Tkinter window always fit with any screen size?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making an application with Tkinter in Python and also using "fullscreen" attributes for my window. When I set an object in this window, it's size and position fit with my screen size, but when I borrow another laptop to test my application, the size and position don't fit with this laptop's screen size (I use "place" and "pack" for setting position). Does anyone know how to make the size and position of objects in the Tkinter window always fit on any screen size? Please help!

I have tried to use object_width = laptop_screen_width - 100, object_height = laptop_screen_height - 100 but I don't know this way is actually right way or not and I have no idea about how to get fitted position for objects.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using `place`? If so, that's usually the most difficult way to make your UI responsive. You almost never need to set the width or height of widgets in pixels. You're going to have to show us some code that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here is something that you can use to get the width and height from any laptop/pc, use.

```
from tkinter import *

win= Tk()

screen_width = win.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = win.winfo_screenheight()
print(screen_width)
print(screen_height)
```

But I don't exactly know how to use these numbers to set the screen size.